# Linq lambda arguments

Tags: c#, linq

I have many linq queries, only difference is values.

```
string x = "foo1";
string y = "foo2"
foo.Where(m => m.Descendants(x).Any(v => v.Value.Contains(y)))
```

How can I use x and y like a variable, maybe I need extract linq in another method and how it I can do?

Comment: Well what are `x` and `y` meant to be? Your question is unclear at the moment... a full concrete example would be really useful.

Comment: @Vlad, `x` and `y` are values from some array?

Comment: @user2167382 they are strings

Comment: Assuming that `.Descendants(string)` is a method on `m` returning a collection, containing somethat that has a `Value` property/field that returns something on which `.Contains(y)` will work, I fail to see what the problem is here. Does the code as posted work? If so, what is the question?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have many linqs, so I want use method to nake my code cleaner.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, it all works

Comment: So then what is the question? You're asking if you can use x and y like variables, you're already doing that.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I want extract it to another function

Comment: So have you tried it? taking x and y as parameters?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes, I already solve it with lambda expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solve for my problem with lambda expressions, thanks @Selman22 for idea.

```
Func<IEnumerable<XElement>, string, string, IEnumerable<XElement>> functionSearch;
functionSearch = (l, x, y) => l.Where(m => m.Descendants(x).Any(v => v.Value.Contains(y)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> GetElements(this XElement foo, string x, string y)
{ 
    return foo.Where(m => m.Descendants(x).Any(v => v.Value.Contains(y)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply copy the method signature. Put your cursor on Descendants and hit F12.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I need a good reason to use XPath or Linq to do element parsing instead of deserializing XML to hard type class elements. Like Selman22 you can write extension method

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<XElement> GetElements(
        this XElement foo, string x, string y)
    { 
        return foo.Where(m => m.Descendants(x).Any(v => v.Value.IndexOf(y)>-1))
    }
}
```

After that you can use :

```
var item = foo.GetElements(x,y);
```